# Maximal Cohen-Macaulay of finite flat dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $(R,\frak{m})$ be a commutative Cohen-Macaulay local ring and $M$ a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module of Krull dimension $d$. If $M$ has a finite flat dimension, is it true to say that its injective dimension is finite?

Comment: If $\operatorname{id}R<\infty$ (i.e. Gorenstein) then the result is true.

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34709/479623) answer. It mentioned a result of Foxby that such ring must be Gorenstein

Comment: Ok, you are right.Thank you for your reminder.